# Ag-grid column grouping resize issue

Tags: ag-grid

In my developed grid with column grouping, there is white empty space is appear at end when resize the columns. Any Suggestion?[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can call `sizeColumnsToFit()` after `columnRowGroupChanged` event:

> [**`columnRowGroupChanged`**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#columns)   A row group column was added or removed.

`.html` template event binding

```
(columnRowGroupChanged)="groupChanged($event)"
```

or `.ts` `gridOptions` event binding (don't forget to define `[gridOptions]` in `.html`)

```
this.gridOptions:{
    onColumnRowGroupChanged : this.groupChanged.bind(this)
}
```

handling

```
groupChanged(params){
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rUwPD35gBP6PEDU7rXdX?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: .thanks for your reply.
I tried your suggestion.But not resolved.

Comment: Thanks for demo.In demo u can see some white empty space at right end.Thats the issue. can we resolve?

Comment: demo image is added in my question.

Comment: need after group changed.

Comment: pls, try after resize any columns. some empty space at right end.

Comment: for handle it there is another event `columnResized`, but `sizeColumnsToFit` will also execute `columnResized`, so you need to handle somehow with check property to avoid the `loop`

Comment: ya. issue needs to resolve on resize columns.can we?

Comment: sorry my bad you have this question on top, and I've understand question not fully correct

Comment: tried in column resized. Because of loop, the page got unresponsive.How to avoid Looping?

Comment: you can [try this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#shift-resizing): `colResizeDefault='shift'` which means that resize (out of cell range) would be possible only with: hold `shift` + resize

Comment: "colResizeDefault='shift'" works in children columns. But not worked in parent group column resize.

Comment: to avoid loop in columnResized handler, you should check the event.source and distinguish between manually triggered event via D&D of resizer (right header edge) and event caused by api call (sizeColumnsToFit)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from ag-grid **23.1.0**, we no longer have to use sizeColumnsToFit. Instead, in column definition, add flex: 1 to the last visible column.

This prevents all annoying jumps and weird grid behavior when resizing columns. In case user enlarge the column, horizontal scrollbar will appear, which is the expected behavior.
Please go over your code and change sizeColumnsToFit to the flex solution.
Flex also gives you control over relative column sizes, you can read more about it in the docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/.

Example:

```
columnDefs = [{...}
               ...
             {
                headerName: 'HeaderA',
                field: 'name',
                ...
                flex: 1, // Adding this to last column definition
              }]
```